# Как сделать такие цифры

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такие цифры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91360/discussion-on-question-by-leks----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

делаем прозрачный текст, и контур черный, почти прозрачный.

```css
p {
  font-size: 10rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #ff000000;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 6.3px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/no-translate-detected_23-2147830190.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="bg">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Leks пожалуйста